# html/php form to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am new to coding and stackoverflow so I apologise in advance. I have looked through stackoverflow but cannot find the answer to my problem. I have a html form set up which then saves the email and password to mysql no problem. I wish to add name, DOB, Town, Country to these inputs which I have done so in the html below:

```
<form class="marginTop" method="post">

                <div class="form-group"> 
                  <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                                <input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Katie" type="text" value="<? echo addslashes($_POST['name']); ?>" />
                    </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                    <!-- email panel -->
                        <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Katie@katie.com" type="email" value="<? echo addslashes($_POST['email']); ?>" />

                </div>


                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">DOB</span>
                    <!-- DOB panel -->
                        <input name="DOB" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" type="DOB" value="<? echo addslashes($_POST['DOB']); ?>" />

                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Town/City</span>
                    <!-- Place panel -->
                        <input name="Town" class="form-control" placeholder="New York" type="town" value="<? echo addslashes($_POST['town']); ?>" />

                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Country</span>
                    <!-- country panel -->

                        <input name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="America" type="country" value="<? echo addslashes($_POST['country']); ?>" />

                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Password</span>
                    <!-- password panel -->
                        <input name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="At least 8 characters and 1 cap letter" type="password" value="<? echo addslashes($_POST['password']); ?>" />  


                </div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-success btn-lg marginTop"/>


            </form>
```

The line in the php doc that encrupts the password and adds it along with the email to mysql is this. This works fine, what I am struggling with is adding `Name`, `DOB`, `Town` and `Country`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
```

I thought i could simply add these to this line of code but i get errors when I do. For example like this with adding `name` to it.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']).$_POST['name'])."')";
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, like I said I am new to this so be gentle on me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to separate email and name, `.$_POST['password']).$_POST['name'])."')";` change it to: `.$_POST['password']) . "', '" . $_POST['name']."')";`

Comment: Thanks very much in helping out. I have tried this and it comes back with this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: I've worked it out. just needed to nudge up a space that was not needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']))."','".$_POST['name']."')";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried this and it comes back with this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: I've worked it out. There was a space that was not needed. Works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @Epodax stated, instead of separating your values (password and name) you are concatenating them.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']).$_POST['name']."')";
```

Should be...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']). "', '" . $_POST['name']."')";
```

Comment: I have tried this and it comes back with this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: I've worked it out. There was one closed bracket by `name` that was not needed. I deleted it and now it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @will, if the answer is correct would you mind accepting it?

Comment: sorry new to this and forgot to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']))."','".$_POST['name']."')";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11730147)